# Current density from amperes law

Tags: electromagnetism

I wanted to find the current density ${\bf J}$ in a wire that gives rise to a magnetic field ${\bf B}$ along the closed curve that encloses the area of some disk with radius $r$ with normal vector parallel to the wire. To do this I'm using that

${\bf B}(r) = \frac{\alpha}{r}{\bf e_\theta}$ and that

$\nabla \times{\bf B} = \mu_0 {\bf J}$ in order to find the current density ${\bf J}$. However, when I calculate this using $\nabla$ in sylindrical coordinates I get that $\nabla \times {\bf B}= 0$.

My question is, why don't I get the current density out of this equation? I'm really confused now.

Comment: " with normal vector parallel to the wire" I don't think this is right...

Comment: http://labman.phys.utk.edu/phys222core/modules/m4/images/wire1.gif It's such a situation. The normalvector of the imagined disk points along the wire.

Comment: curl B applies to the field at a point, not around a closed curve. If curl B is zero then there is no current density at that point.

Comment: And you apply the curl theorem? or why is that you are working with a curve? If don't, your vector field $\textbf{B}$ must have an $\textbf{e}_r$ term.

Comment: Raul, first I derived the form of the magnetic field at a distance $r$ from a wire. Then I wanted to go backwards and find the current density by using the equation I wrote, but it seems that it isn't possible by what Rob pointed out.

Comment: I googled curl and now I understand why what I wrote doesn't even make sense. Thanks Rob, for pointing it out to me.

Comment: You get the current density, there is just one point you did not handle properly.

Comment: Don't you need the thickness of the wire?

Answer (score 1):

If the B-field has the form you suggest, which is appropriate for the magnetic field *outside* a wire, then the curl is zero. This makes perfect sense since there is *no current density outside the wire*.

The B-field *inside* the wire has a different form and has a non-zero z-component in its curl.

The relationship between the curl B and the current density applies at a point. It is not used around closed curves.